# 11 combinations of quintic functions

Tags: roots, combinations

I want to find out the 11 possible combinations of real (distinct and equal) and complex roots for a quintic function.

For example a quintic function with...

2 real distinct and 3 real equal 
or
1 real distinct and 4 complex

I know there are 11 combinations but I'm missing a few

Answer (score 0):

The number of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $5$ is $7$:

- into $5:~1,1,1,1,1$
- into $4:~1,1,1,2$
- into $3:~1,2,2~$ and $~1,1,3$
- into $2:~1,4~$ and $2,3$
- into $1:~5$.

~ In the ***first*** case, all five roots are distinct. Since complex roots can only come in [pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem), we have ***three*** such possibilities, corresponding to the number of $0,~1$, and respectively $2$ complex conjugate pairs.

~ In the ***second*** case, we have one double root, and the other three are distinct. ***Two*** possibilities. Obviously, the double root cannot be complex, since that would automatically imply the existence of another complex conjugate double root.

~ In the ***third*** case, we have two distinct double roots, and a fifth root, also distinct. ***Two*** possible situations: either all five roots are real, or a double root is complex, implying that the other double root is its complex conjugate.

~ In the ***fourth*** case, we have one triple root, and the other two are distinct. ***Two*** possible options, depending on whether the latter two are real, or complex conjugates.

~ In the ***fifth*** case, we have a quadruple root, and a distinct root, all real, for obvious reasons.

~ In the ***sixth*** case, we have a double root, and a triple root, both real, for obvious reasons.

~ In the ***seventh*** and last case, we have a quintuple real root $($again, for obvious reasons$)$.

> *So there are **twelve** possible cases, in total.*